# Get process instance id for restarted process

Tags: java, camunda

I am using Camunda and I want to restart already completed process. I am doing that using the following logic:

```
ProcessEngines.getDefaultProcessEngine()
            .getRuntimeService()
            .restartProcessInstances(processInstance.getProcessDefinitionId())
            .processInstanceIds(processInstanceId)
            .startBeforeActivity(processInstance.getStartActivityId())
            .initialSetOfVariables()
            .execute();
```

And this works great but after it is restarted I am not able to get the process instance id of the newly started process since the execute method is of type void. Anyone know how I am able to get the process instance id of the new process?

Comment: Does the process instance have a business key?  If yes, try querying for running process and the business key.

Comment: @AndrewS unfortunately I don't have a business key for this process.

Answer (score 0):

By the time you restart a task, the task ID is new and the processInstanceId will be new

Comment: I know that, but my question is how to get the process instance id after this execute. I need to do some things with that process after but I am not able to get the process instance id.